# Android Studio: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, android-studio, java.util.scanner

I am trying to run the following code in Android Studio and getting the shown error. Actually, whenever I use `scanner.nextLine()`, I get a similar error.

```
    package com.example.javalib;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ChallengeThirteen {

        public static void main(String[] args)  {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Your name is "+ name);

        }
    }
```

Error:

> ```
> > Task :JavaLib:ChallengeThirteen.main() FAILED
> Enter your name: 
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>   at com.example.javalib.ChallengeThirteen.main(ChallengeThirteen.java:12)
>
> Execution failed for task ':JavaLib:ChallengeThirteen.main()'.
> > Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with
> ```
>
> non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using Android Studio. Android Studio is specifically designed to write applications for Android, and is not designed to be able to create standalone java applications. I would recommend using IntelliJ IDEA instead of Android Studio as its interface is practically identical and it supports standalone applications. You will also get a command line when you run a program, which will let you use the System.in input stream and will get rid of this error entirely. This error occured because Android Studio does not let you use the System.in input stream from the command line by default, which means it will not detect a line for the Scanner object.

Comment: No I have created a separate java library. And running this as a Java Class.

Comment: BTW how to set up System.in input stream?

Comment: it depends - how are you running the class file?

Comment: Using rightclick and choosing the "Run Filename.main()" option to run the program

Comment: Android Studio is designed mainly for creating Android applications. I would recommend switching to IntelliJ IDEA if you want to develop and test standalone java applications, because then you will get a command line when you run your programs. I am editing my answer to reflect this

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that. Was learning Java in studio itself as my ultimate aim is android application development. If others are able to rectify above problem, please suggest. it would be helpful

Comment: I've revised my answer to explain where this error came from and how to fix it